# IOException: 'Cannot locate resource' in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I have a WPF program, with a main window, which utilizes some resource dictionaries, located in a subfolder, as you can see here (we will soon get to, why I highlighted one of them):

[image: File structure in my project]

In the top of my **MainWindow.xaml**, I include some of these resource dictionaries, like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>      
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/XamlResources/ControlTemplates.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/XamlResources/TextBlockStyles.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/XamlResources/Styles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So obviously everything is as it should be, and the program does compile and run just fine. No exceptions, no warnings, all is good. Except it's not. Because in the Visual Studio Editor, this is what the design window shows:

[image: IOException in the Visual Studio editor.]

Why do I get this error, when everything apparently is as it should be? I have event tried using the "Find" feature to search for other occurrences of **controltemplate.xaml**, but I only find valid references. Is this some sort of Visual Studio bug, and if so, how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Fiddling around with the XAML (for instance changing the way the source is formatted) sometimes causes the error to change to an SqlException, like this:

[image: SqlException, which sometimes occur instead of the IOException.]

I have no idea why this happens, or why the exception seems to change from time to time. I am using **Entity Framework**, if that could be the root cause, but I do not have a local SQL server installed. However, this hasn't been a problem in previous projects.

Comment: Did you try <ResourceDictionary Source="XamlResources/ControlTemplates.xaml" />?

Comment: @Kaspar I have tried that. It doesn't change a whole lot. However, sometime the error changes to an **XamlParseException** instead. It still states though, that i cannot locate resource `xamlresource/controltemplates.xaml`.

Comment: Have you checked the encoding of the file? I've had in the past the encoding being changed from utf-8 to utf-8 with signature which Visual Studio dislikes.

Comment: @Coops not sure how to check that. I haven't changed the encoding (at least not on purpose), also wouldn't that break the program entirely?

Comment: Open the file in Notepad++ and there's an encoding menu, just check that it's utf-8 and not utf-8 signed.

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar setup in our application and use this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>      
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/Your.Assembly.Name;component/XamlResources/TextBlockStyles.xaml" />
      <!-- ... -->
 </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Fun stuff. If I make this changes, the designer displays the actual window (and content) for like a second, before then throwing a new exception, this time an `SqlException` (still at design time, no compiling or running the program).

Comment: @Noceo I wouldn't worry about on the designer preview too much, it's pretty finicky and often doesn't work although a control or window works when actually run. However the SqlException hints that loading of the styles now works and it has run in new issues in displaying data from your controls.